# JSF exception handling

Tags: java, jsf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSF 1.2 Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347692/jsf-1-2-exception-handling)

In my appliation, once an application error occurs or a system error occur, we throw the exception and catch right at the backing bean. In the backing bean i caught the exception and i converted the exception to FacesContext message as follows

```
/**
* 
*/
public void createFacesExceptionMsg(Exception e){   
    String caughtAt = e.getStackTrace()[0].toString();
        if (null != caughtAt && !caughtAt.isEmpty()) {
            getFacesContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage   (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                    caughtAt, null));
        } else {
            getFacesContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                    "Local message not set when Exception thrown - Application in error state", null));
        }           
}
```

i have to render the exception on a errorpage.jsp.

How to print the facesContext Message on the errorPage.jsp

Its jsf1.2

Answer (score 1):

just put

```
<h:messages />
```

in your jsp

Comment: The vague question indeed leaves some ambiguity; I think that OP's actual problem is the showing of the error page itself in the same request, which is indeed not *that* obvious ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you throw a regular java exception within your web application, you can have access to it using the implicit page scoped object `${pageContext.exception}`. You have access to this object only within the page that is designated as the error page either by page level declaration

```
   <%@ pageisErrorPage=”true”%>
```

or in your deployment descriptor.

If you're using the new jsp 2.x, you can have access to the newer `javax.servlet.jsp.ErrorData` as `${pageContext.errorData` which gives you some information on the exception via member variables like

1. requestURI : The URI for the offending request
2. servletName : The name of the servlet / JSP page that failed.
3. statusCode: the Http status code
4. throwable : the actual exception object and associated member fields.

Comment: i did the same thing like you told, it works and takes me back to the error page, but i have few control buttons on the jsp which are not displayed. My work in the project is once the exception occurs in the system, i need to take control of the exception, catch it and convert into faces message and display that on the error.jsp, invalidate the session and there must be way to navigate back to main menu from the jsp.

Comment: @ylnsagar,share the markup on your error page here. I'm assuming you've added the jsf `taglib` declarations on that page?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly what you are trying to do is

1. Catch exception
2. Put a facesMessage to Context
3. Redirect to error.jsp
4. Display facesMessage on error.jsp

> In a JSF Reference Implementation, passing global faces messages
> between pages doesn’t work. It’s not designed that way “out of the
> box.” Fortunately there is a way to do this, which will even support
> redirects between pages, forwards through a RequestDispatcher, and
> also through standard JSF navigation cases.

If this is what you want to do here you go

### [Persist and pass FacesMessages over multiple page redirects](http://ocpsoft.org/java/persist-and-pass-facesmessages-over-page-redirects/)

---

If you need a way to handle exceptions with redirection, like

- sessionExpired.xhtml
- loginRequired.xhtml
- pageNotFound.xhtml

Read about ExceptionHandlerFactory from the developer of JSF (Ed Burns)

### [Dealing Gracefully ViewExpiredException - JSF 2.0](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2)

---

### UPDATE AFTER OP COMMENT

Follow these steps and let me know if it works.

1. Use ExceptionHandler (as explained @[Ed Burn's Blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2))
2. Register your facesMessage in `handle()` method of your `ExceptionHandler`
3. Put `<h:messages/>` to your error.jsp to view it.
4. To invalidate session or to navigate to main menu use `errorPageBean.action()` from your `erroPage.jsp`

Comment: My error.jsp has also a control button, which navigates back to main menu. I just have to display the faces message in the error.jsp, invalidate the session and navigate back to main menu.