# JSF 1.2 Exception Handling

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, exception

I am working on exception handling in our Application. I used try catch blocks to catch the exceptions occured in my code and i also could handle the time out exceptions by writing a listener and registering the listener in "faces-config.xml".

But i am facing problems in catching unexpected errors like "NullPointerException" in constructor or error Codes 500, 400 etc.

i used the tags in the "web.xml"

```
<error-page>
      <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
      <location>/sc00/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I tried many ways to handle the exceptions, can any one help me in finding out a solution. The error i am getting when i try to handle these exceptions is as follows.

I am using JSF 1.2 and the server is websphere 8

The Console shows the Following Exception.

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause Faces Servlet: javax.servlet.ServletException

E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [/sc00/ErrorPage.jsp] in application [MembershipEligibilityScreensEAR]. Exception created : [java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found
```

My Error Page is in /WebContent/sc00/ErrorPage.jsp, ErrorPage.jsp has no backing bean  associated with it.

Many solutions asked me to look at the URL path of Faces Servlet, In My web.xml the servlet-mapping is a follows

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

all the paths in my faces-config.xml refer to /FolderName/JspName and they work fine and they work fine even in Navigation.xml.

How can i navigate it to ErrorPage.jsp, Is there any way so that i can write a listener to this kind of problem

Sorry for posting too many redundant questions, i am new to JSF and i don't know the rules of StackOverflow, I apologize for the problem i have caused.

any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a JSF problem but generic Java Web Application.

Comment: do you have any solution on how to overcome the above problem?. I don't understand why you are saying its not JSF problem, The Exception clearly occurs in the backing bean's constructor and i am unable to handle that.

Comment: You can come with a NPE in a JSP like this: `<% String s = null; s.length(); %>`. The NPE will arise and it will be printed in the JSP (did you see a JFS code there? I haven't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found
```

That will happen when you're requesting a JSP page containing JSF components through an URL which doesn't match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` (who is the one responsible for creating the `FacesContext`).

You need to change the error page location to match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as definited in `web.xml`. Based on your [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939747/ylnsagar?tab=questions) on the subject, this is among others `*.faces`, so setting the error page location as follows should do, exactly as I suggested in a comment on your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297507/jsf-session-timeout-exception-handling#comment18136428_13297507) on the subject.

```html
<location>/sc00/ErrorPage.faces</location>
```

Comment: I tried that but its not working. i really tried a million times i also created a html page named "error.html" its not working. i request you to look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353198/jsf-1-2-web-xml-and-exception-handling. In this question i also posted the web.xml, so that you can find if there are any configuration errors. i got many solution for JSF 2, but JSF1.2 there are not many solutions for this case. Can you please suggest me is there any way to write a listener or filter. the reason for repetitive questions is i am not getting the answers that solves the problem

Comment: <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> these are the two URL patterns in web.xml

Comment: It's impossible that you get a `java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found` when using `error.html` instead of a JSP page with JSF components. Please tell about the new error you get when using `error.html` instead. You should absolutely not ignore errors as if they are decoration. As to re-asking the same question everytime, that's not how it works here. If you don't get (satisfying) answers, just edit and improve your question.